# Can RestEasy extends @Path?

Tags: java, rest, path, resteasy

```
@Path("a")
public class A {}

@Path("b")
public class B extends A {
    @GET
    getList(){}
}
```

I want a path to be GET localhost/rest/v1/a/b

Is it a way to do this? simple extending doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotations can be *inherited*, but they are not extended or concatenated or anything like that. Put it this way - the `@Path` on `B` completely erases the `@Path` from `A`. (Without `B`'s `@Path`, it would inherit the `@Path` from `A`, possibly leading to a deployment conflict, but that's neither here nor there.)

There are two ways, off the top of my head, to do this. The first, of course, simply involves doing this:

```
@Path("a/b")
public class B ...
```

The second involves sub-resources (section 3.4.1 of [the JAX-RS 2.0 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxrs-2_0_rev_A-mrel-eval-spec/index.html))...

```
@Path("a")
public class A {

    @Path("b")
    public B getB() {
       return new B();
    }
}

public class B {
    // blah blah blah
}
```

Two things here I want to highlight:

1. `B` has no `@Path` of its own. It is a subresource, not directly accessible except through `A`. The total path to B is the concatenation of the application path, `A`'s path, and `B`s path on the subresource locator (`getB()`), with appropriate `/`s.
2. `B` does not inherit from `A`. If it did, as I said above, it would inherit `A`'s @Path. This could produce a conflict, or lead to `A` being ignored in favor of the more specific subtype `B`. (See section 3.6 of the spec for details of annotation inheritance, and section 3.7 for exactly how a matching class/method is chosen for a given request.)